# mySQL queries are executed twice on wordpress website

Tags: php, query, mysql, sql

I'm sorry for my english.
I'm trying to add some functionalities at my Wordpress website and to do this i have added a function in my function.php theme. The idea is to save in a custom table some datas and create a wp_post for any element added in the custom table.

I hooked the function in this way:

```
add_action ( 'init', 'inserimentoAutoDatabase' );
```

The problem is that when the function is executed the query that save the datas in the custom table and create a new post is executed twice. I report my code:

```
function inserimentoAutoDatabase(){

    //get datas from an xml file
    $result = fetchData("http://dealer.drivek.it/myPortalXML/index?myPortalXMLkey=d660d1e9-8c1d-41ff-8f54-0829777a9960");

    //save the xml  
    $fp = fopen('autodealerk-1.xml', 'w+');
    fwrite($fp, $result);
    fclose($fp);

    //load xml file
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("autodealerk-1.xml");

    $i=0;

    //start parsing xml content
    foreach($xml->car as $auto)
    {
        //this echo is executed only once
        echo ("test");

        //not important for the question | checks some content
        if($auto->km == null || $auto->km  == ''){
            $kilometri = "nuova";
            $anno_registrazione = "-";
        }else{
            $kilometri = $auto->km;
            $anno_registrazione = $auto->registrationDate;
        }

        $inevidenza = 0;
        if($auto->tractionType){
            $inevidenza = 1;
        }


        // create an array for the query
        $insData = array(
            'id' => $auto['id'],
            'make' => (string) $auto->make,
            'model' => (string) $auto->model,
            'version' => (string) $auto->version,
            'bodyType' => $auto->bodyType,
            'fuelType' => $auto->fuelType,
            'type' => $auto->type,
            'dealer_name' => (string) $auto->dealer->name,
            'gear_gearType' => (string) $auto->gear->gearType,
            'tractionType' => $auto->tractionType,
            'kw' => $auto->kw,
            'doors' => $auto->doors,
            'seats' => $auto->seats,
            'emissionClass' => $auto->emissionClass,
            'prices_listPrices' => $auto->prices->listPrice,
            'exterior_color_paint' => $auto->exterior->color . " " . $auto->exterior->paint,
            'km' => $kilometri,
            'typewarrantyMonths' =>  $auto->warranty->type . " " . $auto->warranty->warrantyMonths,
            'equipments' => "equipaggiamenti",
            'media' => $auto->image,
            'description' => $auto->description,
            'registrationDate' => $anno_registrazione
        );

        $wpdb->insert('auto_importate', $insData);


        // define the post
        $my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => (string) $auto->make . (string) $auto->model . (string) $auto->version,
          'post_content'  => $auto->description,
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1,
          'post_type'     => "vehicles"
        );

        // ***** post is created twice
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );


        //i break the cycle **** only for test
        $i++;
        if( $i == 1 ) break;

    }
}
```

As you can see in the images below at the end of the cicle (breaked after the first execution) i expect only one element but there are twice.

[image: auto_importate table]

[image: auto_importate table content]

Anyone can help me??? Have you any idea about this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/27585/4771

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work for me

Comment: @Rarst Comment is now an answer.  In these instances, do I delete my comment??

Comment: @ECarterYoung mods usually do it, even if not - no harm  really :)

Comment: any additional request will trigger your code, for example a 404 on an asset served in the first request will result in another request hitting WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `wpdb->insert` and `wp_insert_post` both accomplish an SQL Insert, which is why you're seeing 2 records each time.  You must use only one instance of an insert method, and then Pass `$my_post` to `WP_Query`

**CLARIFICATION**

As Milo points out in his comment `wpdb->insert` will insert into any table, while `wp_insert_post` is used to insert a post into the wp_posts table.  `wpdb->insert` is used mainly for custom tables.

In your case:

```
<?php $wpdb->insert( 'auto_importare', $insData); ?>
```

Sticking with the premise that $wpdb should be used for custom tables, you would then use `wpdb->get_results` to select the data you just inserted:

```
<?php $post_results -> $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT make,model, version,description FROM wpdb->auto_importare'); ?>
```

Lastly, and this part escapes me at the moment, you would build your post query from `$post_results`

See [The WordPress Codex: wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: they both insert, but the data is going into two different tables.

Answer (score 0):

You make no attempt to check if the work has already been done. As a result on every page load the work will be done yet again and more posts created.

Because of this, when WordPress attempts to run WP Cron, you'll get a second load, and a second run of the code.

So do not run this on every page load via the init hook. The URL being fetched takes a long time to return the full page so your site will run very slowly.

Instead:

- Run this in a cron job that runs at regular intervals
- Check before inserting if the post has already been created. Perhaps by querying the `auto_importate` table to see if a car with that ID already exists.

A final note, you do not need the `auto_importate` table, use custom fields/post meta instead. You may also want to get a new portal key now that you've posted it for all to see in your question